# How do I align numbers in my table using dcolumn?

Tags: tables

I need help with this table.
Values ​​are aligned to 5 decimal places and I must use `dcolumn`.  This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\caption{Experimentální výsledky}
\label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{ l c c r r r }
\toprule
 & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ & $\delta$ & $\chi$ \\ \hline
 Pokus 1 & 9,03983 & 20,7265 & 70,905 & -31,83 & -75,2 \\ \hline
 \multirow{4}{*}{Pokus 2} & 84,99683 & -88,7 & 33,551 & 83,436 & -59,9\\ 
         & -67 & -81,46 & -98 & 54,0456 & -28\\ 
         & -23,8 & -63 & -9,47 & 58,03674 & -89,1\\ 
         & -61,4 & -68,19 & -13,2 & -80,2 & -47,3\\ \hline
 Pokus 6 & -87,94 & -52 & 68,548 & 17,0284 & -49,1 \\ \hline
 Pokus 7 & -72,55 & -66,06 & -50 & -66,3 & 92,27074\\ \hline
 Pokus 8 & 12,475 & 73,464 & 23,9323 & 52,959 & -87,71\\ \hline
 Pokus 9 & 99,24615 & -27,17 & 49,5099 & 88,7448 & 87,22619\\ \hline
 Pokus 10 & 99,268 & 83,8816 & -94,4 & -25,5 & 47,873\\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I appreciate that you've formatted your code.  To clarify, is the picture your desired output, but you're not quite there yet?  And you want to use dcolumn to align on the decimal?  (Also, instead of making each line code by itself, it's better to highlight the entire thing and click `{}` to make a block of code.  And if you can start off with `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}`, then we can copy and paste this into a blank tex file.)

Comment: I can't really get the question. How would you like it to be?

Comment: The first picture is as it should be. I have this https://ctrlv.cz/FlNX

Comment: Why should you use `dcolumn` and not `siunitx`?

Comment: @Alfred: Can you use a better title for you question? Something that's more specific that "Help with table".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The changes I made with respect to your MWE are the following:

1. you can use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` inside the table environment
2. you need to embed the content of the first row (the heading) in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` command to override the `D` column type
3. the syntax `*{n}{t}` allows you to define `n` columns of type `t`
4. I added the `\otoprule` separator so that you can have the same line thickness of `\toprule` but equal spacing between the rows for the headings
5. the extra spacing between the columns (which appears in your reference image) can be achieved with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}`. Instead of `10pt` you can put the length you prefer. If you want to stick with the default column spacing, just comment out the line.
6. Even though in your reference image the caption is at the bottom of the table, it is better to keep it on top, as you already did.

So you have:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]} % vertically centered with respect to the row above and below, but same thickness as \{top,bottom}rule

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Experimentální výsledky}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l *{5}{D{,}{,}{3.5}}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\beta$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\gamma$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\delta$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\chi$} \\ \otoprule
        Pokus 1                  & 9,03983  & 20,7265 & 70,905  & -31,83   & -75,2      \\ \midrule
        \multirow{4}{*}{Pokus 2} & 84,99683 & -88,7   & 33,551  & 83,436   & -59,9      \\
                                 & -67      & -81,46  & -98     & 54,0456  & -28        \\
                                 & -23,8    & -63     & -9,47   & 58,03674 & -89,1      \\
                                 & -61,4    & -68,19  & -13,2   & -80,2    & -47,3      \\ \midrule
        Pokus 6                  & -87,94   & -52     & 68,548  & 17,0284  & -49,1      \\ \midrule
        Pokus 7                  & -72,55   & -66,06  & -50     & -66,3    & 92,27074   \\ \midrule
        Pokus 8                  & 12,475   & 73,464  & 23,9323 & 52,959   & -87,71     \\ \midrule
        Pokus 9                  & 99,24615 & -27,17  & 49,5099 & 88,7448  & 87,22619   \\ \midrule
        Pokus 10                 & 99,268   & 83,8816 & -94,4   & -25,5    & 47,873     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys you are awesome!

Comment: Thanks! consider upvoting/accepting the answer ;)

Comment: +1. Do change `D{,}{,}{2.5}` to `D{,}{,}{3.5}`, though, in order to leave space for the `-` ("minus") symbols.

Comment: Indeed better, thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you not need to load the `dcolumn` package twice :-)

Comment: Indeed I don't :)

Answer (score 4):

With `siunitx` and correct defined numbers format the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\caption{Experimentální výsledky}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=-2.5]
              *{2}{S[table-format=-2.4]}
              *{2}{S[table-format=-2.5]}
               }
        \toprule
        & {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} & {$\gamma$} & {$\delta$} & {$\chi$} \\ 
        \midrule
Pokus 1     & 9,03983  & 20,7265 & 70,905  & -31,83   & -75,2 \\ 
        \midrule
Pokus 1     & 9,03983  & 20,7265 & 70,905  & -31,83   & -75,2 \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Pokus 2}
            & 84,99683 & -88,7   & 33,551  & 83,436   & -59,9       \\
            & -67      & -81,46  & -98     & 54,0456  & -28         \\
            & -23,8    & -63     & -9,47   & 58,03674 & -89,1       \\
            & -61,4    & -68,19  & -13,2   & -80,2    & -47,3       \\
    \midrule
Pokus 6     & -87,94   & -52     & 68,548  & 17,0284  & -49,1       \\
Pokus 7     & -72,55   & -66,06  & -50     & -66,3    & 92,27074    \\
Pokus 8     & 12,475   & 73,464  & 23,9323 & 52,959   & -87,71      \\
Pokus 9     & 99,24615 & -27,17  & 49,5099 & 88,7448  & 87,22619    \\
Pokus 10    & 99,268   & 83,8816 & -94,4   & -25,5    & 47,873      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

`siunitx` enable simple rounding all number for example to three decimal digits:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,},
             round-mode=places,
             round-precision=3,
             round-integer-to-decimal,
             table-format=-2.3            
             }          
\caption{Experimentální výsledky}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{ l *{5}{S} }
        \toprule
        & {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} & {$\gamma$} & {$\delta$} & {$\chi$} \\ 
        \midrule
Pokus 1     & 9,03983  & 20,7265 & 70,905  & -31,83   & -75,2 \\ 
        \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Pokus 2}
            & 84,99683 & -88,7   & 33,551  & 83,436   & -59,9       \\
            & -67      & -81,46  & -98     & 54,0456  & -28         \\
            & -23,8    & -63     & -9,47   & 58,03674 & -89,1       \\
            & -61,4    & -68,19  & -13,2   & -80,2    & -47,3       \\
    \midrule
Pokus 6     & -87,94   & -52     & 68,548  & 17,0284  & -49,1       \\
Pokus 7     & -72,55   & -66,06  & -50     & -66,3    & 92,27074    \\
Pokus 8     & 12,475   & 73,464  & 23,9323 & 52,959   & -87,71      \\
Pokus 9     & 99,24615 & -27,17  & 49,5099 & 88,7448  & 87,22619    \\
Pokus 10    & 99,268   & 83,8816 & -94,4   & -25,5    & 47,873      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I will add option for them asap.

Comment: +1. At first, I went for siunitx on istinct myself ;)